# Executing e2e tests on BrowserStack: Location '/' is not valid

Tags: angular, protractor, browserstack

I'm attempting to run the initial out of the box e2e tests that are generated along with everything else for a new Angular project.

This is what my test looks like:

```
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';

describe('angular5-e2e App', () => {
  it('should display welcome message', () => {
    browser.get('/')
      .then(() => {
        let text = element(by.css('app-root h1')).getText();
        expect(text).toEqual('Welcome to app!');
     });
  });
});
```

This runs fine locally with `ng e2e`. When I attempt to do the same thing only on BrowserStack it fails. Here's my configuration

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserstack.user': '<my-username>',
    'browserstack.key': '<my-password>',
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  // directConnect: true,
  // baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  'seleniumAddress': 'http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
};
```

But this fails with the following message:

[image]

What's the problem here? Am I missing something in my config?

**EDIT**

Specifying the absolute url in the test:

```
browser.get('http://localhost:4200/')
      .then(() => {
```

Then resulted in this error:

[image]

Visiting the [page](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular-on-page-load) in the error recommended changing the time Protractor waits, either globally or locally via the call:

> How to change: To change globally, add getPageTimeout:
>   timeout_in_millis to your Protractor configuration file. For an
>   individual call to get, pass an additional parameter:
>   browser.get(address, timeout_in_millis)

So in my `browser.get` I added 15000 as a second parameter (the maximum wait appears to be 11 seconds - though this was because my config had `allScriptsTimeout: 11000` set) and it failed with this error instead:

[image]

**EDIT 2**

I think this is an issue of Protractor not being able to connect to the local Angular app running - assuming my understanding is correct then it (the app) needs to be running locally for it to test via BrowserStack.

I deployed to our testing branch and ran the tests again and they all passed but I'd like this working locally.

Comment: seems related to an open issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7753. you can try the workaround and explicitly specify the full baseURL

Comment: @BountyHunter see my edit. I followed the recommended steps on the site but it made no difference